# Regular Expression for x vowels in word of n length

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in Java that will match a word of n length that has a at least x number of vowels in it.

So far I've come up with the following:

```
// match words that are length 10 and have at least 2 vowels in them
(?=\w{10})(?:[^aeiou\W]*[aeiuo]){2}\w+
```

This seems to work but also matches words greater than length 10, i.e.:

wildernesses - matches

volatilizations - matches

voiceprint - matches (this should be the only match)

I would like it so that the length=10 constraint is enforced.  I suspect that it may have something to do with the fact that I'm adding letters (the vowels) to the length of the string, but I'm not certain.  Any help / guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it compulsory that you must need to use regular expression ?

Comment: @Bhavik Java and JavaScript are _very_ different.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry bro I just placed that'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries, `\b`, to prevent the match happening halfway through a word:

```
\b(?=\w{10}\b)(?:[^aeiou\W]*[aeiuo]){2,}[^aeiou\W]*\b
```

This will match:

> wildernesses **voiceprint** volatilizations

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify greatly by using a simple lookahead (as a java String):

```
"(?i)\\b(?=([^aeiou ]*[aeiou]){2,})[a-z]{10}\\b"
```

Note that all other answers use `\w` for letters, but `\w` includes the underscore character, which is *not* a letter.

`(?i)` turns on case insensitivity.

Comment: should not match "vxyceprznt" from: 
"wildernesses voiceprint vxyceprznt volatilizations"
- I think ".*" violates the word boundaries
- this should work: (?i)\b(?=([a-z]*[aeiou]){2,})[a-z]{10}\b

Comment: @moj you're right the regex did need fixing, but i fixed it another way. thanks for your comment!

Comment: I think "(?=(.*[aeiou].*?\b){2,})" forces one word boundery for every vowel.

Comment: @moj no. there's a non-greedy `.*?` before the end word boundary, which allows it to have any number of characters between the vowel and the `\b`, but being non-greedy it won't skip over a `\b` to do it

Comment: yes, but the whole subexpression with "\b" must match at least 2 times - "vxyceprznt" from "wildernesses voiceprint vxyceprznt volatilizations" still matches - I think the two vowels are scattered over 2 words

Comment: @moj OK. It's actually simpler than I thought. I fixed it now. I tested it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...
(?<=\b|\p{Punct})(?:(?i)(?:aeiou{2,})|(?:a-z&&[^aeiou]{3,}))(?<=\w{10})

Tested this against sample data which seems to work.  In my example, I've accounted for punctuation.